# Reach function of another qml file

Tags: qml

i have a ButtonD.qml file and a main.qml file. there is a setButtonWidth(number) function in ButtonD.qml file and i want to access it from main.qml file. if i want to instantiate ButtonD in main.qml a a button is added to main which i don't want. the ButtonD.qml is added when a button is clicked so this is when it's added to main.qml. i use setButtonWidth to increase the size of the button in ButtonD.qml. setButtonWidth is called when i maximize window size.what should i do? (codes below)

```
 //main.qml
    Rectangle{
            id: decorate
            color: "#c62828"
            width: parent.width
            height: 25
            x:0
            y:0
     Button{
                id: maximaize
                x:1215
                y:-5
                width: 25
                height: 50
                flat: true 
                onClicked: //call setButtonWidth(number)
    }
    }

Rectangle{
...
Button{
onClicked: //adds ButtonD.qml
}
```

and here is the ButtonD.qml in which i want to increase the size:

```
   //ButtonD.qml
Button{
    id: buttonD
    height: 46
    flat: true
    width: 900
 function setButtonWidth(number){
        buttonD.width = number
    }
}
```

Comment: You do it without a function, in a declarative way.

Comment: how? buttonD.width = ... like this?

Comment: `referenceToTheInstanceOfButtonDInTheFileWhereYouCreatedButtonD.width =` something like this.

Comment: ButtonD is added by a javascript file and there is no instance of it

Comment: Of which instance do you want to change the size then? If you call `createObject(...)`, this of course creates a instance of the component. You may just lose the reference to it, if you dont push that into a property somewhere. Then you will need to search for it in the parents children.

Comment: yes i use createObject(). i don't get the part you say i should push into a property...

Comment: createObject() has a return value. What it returns is a reference to the object that has just been created. Define a property (as in my answer to your other question regarding ButtonD) and assign the returned value to it. Otherwise you can't tell your programm, which object's width you want to change. Afterall, you might call `createObject` hundreds of times. So which of those objtects width you want to change?

Comment: Can you give me an example? what should i return from createObject()? how about the property?(var or what)

Comment: createObject() returns the created object. The type of it, is the type of the object you created. So you could write `property ButtonD myDynamicallyCreatedButtonD` and then when you create the object you call `myDynamicallyCreatedButtonD = theButtonDComponent.createObject(...)` - just as I did it in the answer to your other question.